# Why is this proof in diff eq by George Simmons for Schwarz's inequality seemingly arbitrary?

Tags: inner-products, riemann-integration, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In the problem section, there is a problem asking the reader to prove

$$|(f,g)|\le \|f\|\cdot\|g\|$$

where $|(f,g)|$ is the inner product and $\|f\|$ is the norm by defining the function $F(\alpha) = \|f+\alpha g\|^2$ and (I assume this is how they intended) showing how there is at most one root for $\alpha$ and so the discriminant of $F \le 0$ where then the proof follows quickly. It does seem like a simple proof, but I'm wondering if it would be more intuitive to define the inner product (and the norm) as a discrete Riemann sum, expanding the product on the RHS of the Schwarz inequality, then cancelling, working backwards, and taking the limit of the Riemann sum. Is this flawed in some way or is this an actual approach?

Comment: To explain it slightly differently, yes, your proof could be done. But it relies on a hefty development of the properties of inner product spaces, in particular, Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to prove the existence of an orthonormal basis. And you would need to insure that every step of that development does not require Schwarz or else you will have a circular argument. Meanwhile the proffered proof relies only on the definitions of inner products and some basic high-school algebra.